# Why does changing valid SQL Server pipeline references in old projects cause the build to fail?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ssis

I'm currently trying to learn how to build custom SSIS components, a process for which the documentation is awful and awfully sparse. But then I stumbled on a treasure trove of open source components written in VS 2008 for SQL Server 2008. I figured downloading them and exploring how they work would be a fantastic learning opportunity.

They import into VS 2015 and build successfully without issue. But I don't want to test them against SQL Server 2008, which I don't have a copy of. I want them to work against SQL Server 2014.

In theory, this should be easy. Remove their references to the SQL Server SDK pipeline components in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\` and change them to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\` - and if you do this, the project doesn't complain at all.

Except the build fails: silently. No errors are produced in the error list but no dll's are produced either. Checking the output window reveals why:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IDTSComponentMetaData100'
>   could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

And there are various repetitions of that theme, depending on how many DLL's you've replaced. If you double click on one, it takes you to the offending line but VS 2015 doesn't flag the line as problematic. Indeed you can right-click on the offending class, "go to definition" and get a [from metadata] breakdown as you would for any valid reference.

Indeed for the simpler projects one can create a new project in Visual Studio 2015, add the references to the necessary dll's from SQL Server 2014 and then copy and paste the code in its entirety and it will build without complaint.

I have checked the csproj file and the references are updated to their expected versions.

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.SQLServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=x86">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SQLServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

I've never seen VS behave like this before. What's going on, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, worked it out.

The project was set to build against an old version of .Net which wasn't compatible with more recent versions of SQL Server. Changing the Target Framework in the project properties to the most recent version of .Net fixed the problem.

In this particular it uncovered another error saying the project was missing a reference to `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder.Convert`. Adding a reference to `Microsoft.CSharp` fixed that one.